# Java DNS cache viewer

Tags: java, networking, dns

Is there a way to view/dump DNS cached used by java.net api?

Comment: My understanding is you have to have a DNS server to perform caching - a host itself does not cache DNS requests.

Comment: No the host caches. Indeed the JRE (running with a security manager) and browsers "pin" DNS lookups.

Comment: dns resolver libraries typically caches dns results so they don't have to bother the server so much, and provide quicker response to calls

Comment: I don't think java.net does any DNS caching -- this is probably handled by the OS and may not be directly accessible.

Comment: Hmmm.... A little google-fu proves me wrong.  See for instance http://www.verisign.com/stellent/groups/www_ndscs/documents/comnet_resource/030957.pdf

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a script to print the positive and negative DNS address cache.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public class DNSCache {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com");
    InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
    InetAddress.getByName("www.yahoo.com");
    InetAddress.getByName("www.example.com");
    try {
        InetAddress.getByName("nowhere.example.com");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    }

    String addressCache = "addressCache";
    System.out.println(addressCache);
    printDNSCache(addressCache);
    String negativeCache = "negativeCache";
    System.out.println(negativeCache);
    printDNSCache(negativeCache);
  }
  private static void printDNSCache(String cacheName) throws Exception {
    Class<InetAddress> klass = InetAddress.class;
    Field acf = klass.getDeclaredField(cacheName);
    acf.setAccessible(true);
    Object addressCache = acf.get(null);
    Class cacheKlass = addressCache.getClass();
    Field cf = cacheKlass.getDeclaredField("cache");
    cf.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, Object> cache = (Map<String, Object>) cf.get(addressCache);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> hi : cache.entrySet()) {
        Object cacheEntry = hi.getValue();
        Class cacheEntryKlass = cacheEntry.getClass();
        Field expf = cacheEntryKlass.getDeclaredField("expiration");
        expf.setAccessible(true);
        long expires = (Long) expf.get(cacheEntry);

        Field af = cacheEntryKlass.getDeclaredField("address");
        af.setAccessible(true);
        InetAddress[] addresses = (InetAddress[]) af.get(cacheEntry);
        List<String> ads = new ArrayList<String>(addresses.length);
        for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
            ads.add(address.getHostAddress());
        }

        System.out.println(hi.getKey() + " "+new Date(expires) +" " +ads);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In case someone want to run the above code using a security manager. (or converting it to run in a servlet engine which is running using a security manager), following entries in policy file will help: grant {
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.net";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
  permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "*","accept,connect,resolve";

Comment: How can I run it on android?

Answer (score 18):

The [`java.net.InetAddress`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) uses caching of successful and unsuccessful host name resolutions.

From its javadoc:

> The InetAddress class has a cache to
>   store successful as well as
>   unsuccessful host name resolutions.
>
> By default, when a security manager is
>   installed, in order to protect against
>   DNS spoofing attacks, the result of
>   positive host name resolutions are
>   cached forever. When a security
>   manager is not installed, the default
>   behavior is to cache entries for a
>   finite (implementation dependent)
>   period of time. The result of
>   unsuccessful host name resolution is
>   cached for a very short period of time
>   (10 seconds) to improve performance.
>
> If the default behavior is not
>   desired, then a Java security property
>   can be set to a different Time-to-live
>   (TTL) value for positive caching.
>   Likewise, a system admin can configure
>   a different negative caching TTL value
>   when needed.
>
> Two Java security properties control
>   the TTL values used for positive and
>   negative host name resolution caching:
>
> - **networkaddress.cache.ttl**
>     Indicates the caching policy for
>     successful name lookups from the name
>     service. The value is specified as as
>     integer to indicate the number of
>     seconds to cache the successful
>     lookup. The default setting is to
>     cache for an implementation specific
>     period of time.
>
>   A value of -1 indicates "cache
>     forever".
> - **networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl** (default: 10)
>     Indicates the caching
>     policy for un-successful name lookups
>     from the name service. The value is
>     specified as as integer to indicate
>     the number of seconds to cache the
>     failure for un-successful lookups.
>
>   A value of 0 indicates "never cache".
>     A value of -1 indicates "cache
>     forever".

If what you have in mind is dumping the caches (of type `java.net.InetAddress$Cache`) used by `java.net.InetAddress` , they are internal implementation details and thus `private`:

```
/*
 * Cached addresses - our own litle nis, not!
 */
private static Cache addressCache = new Cache(Cache.Type.Positive);

private static Cache negativeCache = new Cache(Cache.Type.Negative);
```

So I doubt you'll find anything doing this out of the box and guess that you'll have to play with reflection to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5):

Above answer does not work in Java 8 anymore.
Here a slight adaption:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DNSCache {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com");
        InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
        InetAddress.getByName("www.yahoo.com");
        InetAddress.getByName("www.example.com");
        try {
            InetAddress.getByName("nowhere.example.com");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        }

        String addressCache = "addressCache";
        System.out.println(addressCache);
        printDNSCache(addressCache);
        String negativeCache = "negativeCache";
        System.out.println(negativeCache);
        printDNSCache(negativeCache);
    }

    private static void printDNSCache(String cacheName) throws Exception {
        Class<InetAddress> klass = InetAddress.class;
        Field acf = klass.getDeclaredField(cacheName);
        acf.setAccessible(true);
        Object addressCache = acf.get(null);
        Class cacheKlass = addressCache.getClass();
        Field cf = cacheKlass.getDeclaredField("cache");
        cf.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, Object> cache = (Map<String, Object>) cf.get(addressCache);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> hi : cache.entrySet()) {
            Object cacheEntry = hi.getValue();
            Class cacheEntryKlass = cacheEntry.getClass();
            Field expf = cacheEntryKlass.getDeclaredField("expiration");
            expf.setAccessible(true);
            long expires = (Long) expf.get(cacheEntry);

            Field af = cacheEntryKlass.getDeclaredField("addresses");
            af.setAccessible(true);
            InetAddress[] addresses = (InetAddress[]) af.get(cacheEntry);
            List<String> ads = new ArrayList<String>(addresses.length);
            for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
                ads.add(address.getHostAddress());
            }

            System.out.println(hi.getKey() + " expires in "
                    + Instant.now().until(Instant.ofEpochMilli(expires), ChronoUnit.SECONDS) + " seconds " + ads);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer does not work with Java 11. In Java 11, both positive and negative cache entries can be retrieved using the 'cache' instance variable.
Here are new adaptations:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class DnsCacheFetcher {
static long startTimeinNano = System.nanoTime();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("SecurityManager: " + System.getSecurityManager());

    InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com");
    InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
    InetAddress.getByName("www.yahoo.com");
    InetAddress.getByName("www.ankit.com");

    try {
        InetAddress.getByName("nowhere.example.com");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unknown host: " + e);
    }

    String addressCache = "cache";
    System.out.println(">>>>" + addressCache);
    printDNSCache(addressCache);
    /*
     * String negativeCache = "negativeCache"; System.out.println(">>>>" +
     * negativeCache); printDNSCache(negativeCache);
     */
}

private static void printDNSCache(String cacheName) throws Exception {
    Class<InetAddress> klass = InetAddress.class;
    Field[] fields = klass.getDeclaredFields();

    /*
     * for (Field field : fields) { System.out.println(field.getName()); }
     */

    Field acf = klass.getDeclaredField(cacheName);
    acf.setAccessible(true);
    Object addressCache = acf.get(null);
    Class cacheKlass = addressCache.getClass();

    Map<String, Object> cache = (Map<String, Object>) acf.get(addressCache);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> hi : cache.entrySet()) {
        /* System.out.println("Fetching cache for: " + hi.getKey()); */
        Object cacheEntry = hi.getValue();
        Class cacheEntryKlass = cacheEntry.getClass();
        Field expf = cacheEntryKlass.getDeclaredField("expiryTime");
        expf.setAccessible(true);
        long expires = (Long) expf.get(cacheEntry);

        Field af = cacheEntryKlass.getDeclaredField("inetAddresses");
        af.setAccessible(true);
        InetAddress[] addresses = (InetAddress[]) af.get(cacheEntry);
        List<String> ads = null;
        if (addresses != null) {
            ads = new ArrayList<String>(addresses.length);
            for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
                ads.add(address.getHostAddress());
            }
        }

        /*
         * System.out.println(hi.getKey() + " expires in " +
         * (Instant.now().until(Instant.ofEpochMilli(expires), ChronoUnit.SECONDS)) +
         * " seconds. inetAddresses: " + ads);
         */

        /*
         * System.nanoTime() + 1000_000_000L * cachePolicy : this how java 11 set
         * expiryTime
         */
        System.out.println(hi.getKey() + " expires in approx " + (expires - startTimeinNano) / 1000_000_000L
                + " seconds. inetAddresses: " + ads);


    }
}}
```

Comment: Note the last closing curly bracket is out of the code block, but needed.
SO won't let me edit since the changes are not at least 6 characters.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/alibaba/java-dns-cache-manipulator

A simple 0-dependency thread-safe Java™ lib for setting/viewing dns programmatically without touching host file, make unit/integration test portable; and a tool for setting/viewing dns of running JVM process.

This lib/tool read and set java dns cache by reflection, with concerns:

- compatibility with different java version(support Java 6/8/11/17).
  dns cache implementation in `java.net.InetAddress` is different in different java version.
- thread-safety
- support IPv6