# Railo Context Change

Tags: coldfusion, tomcat7, railo, ubuntu-13.10

I've got a `Railo Server with Tomcat 7` installed on `Ubuntu Server 13.10` with `Apache2`. I originally installed it on `myrailoserver-dev` and then changed the name of the server to `myrailoserver`.

The issue is that it will only load the scripts when the HTTP-Header has the original name of the server or the original IP address.

The server is behind a Reverse Proxy. If the Proxy passes `myrailoserver-dev` or `192.168.1.49` the cfm files run. I get `Hello World!` in all it's glory. If the proxy passes `myrailoserver`, the current name of the host server, the scripts don't run and I get a huge wall of blank screen.

I can't for the life of me figure out where to change these settings.

Comment: How did you go about changing your hostname? Does your new hostname resolve when you ping it?

Comment: The hostname was changed via /etc/hosts, /etc/hostname, apache2, dns, etc. All of the parts point to the right place. The index file list updates as stuff is changed on the server no matter the incoming http-header. The only thing that changes is that when the http-header is myrailoserver-dev the scripts work... with its myrailoserver they don't.

Comment: They don't _what?_ What messages are in the logs? What happens when you replace the contents of Application.cfc or index.cfm with a `<cfdump eval=cgi abort />` ?

Comment: I wonder if you're hitting a JRE DNS caching issue? See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835421/java-dns-cache-viewer

Comment: @PeterBoughton Exactly. They don't... anything. Blank page. No results. If I go to 192.168.1.49 then `<cfoutput>#ucase("hello world")#</cfoutput>` prints `HELLO WORLD`... if I go to railo.myserver.com it prints... nothing. Empty result page.
`

Comment: @Jordan after playing with settings till my eyes bleed, it's started working. railo, railo-dev, etc all load properly now and the scripts run. I'll have to look into JRE DNS caching.