# Find out domain for given IPv4/IPv6 address (not rDNS/PTR)

Tags: android, linux, dns, language-agnostic

Is it possible to get domain names which resolves to given IPv4/IPv6 address?

I'd guess there must be way in querying system DNS cache, but I haven't found any proper solution.

Also, I'm not interested in rDNS/PTR, which is pretty easy to obtain, but in domain names recently resolved by system, that point to given IP address.

My primary interest is Android OS, but you can give out solutions for other platforms too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835421/java-dns-cache-viewer or http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18002/is-there-a-way-to-list-the-local-dns-cache

Comment: @Appleman1234 It is not, because the question isn't limited to Java SDK, I'm asking about general DNS cache, even that used by binaries, scripts, system libraries, ...

Comment: There is no way of doing this, DNS is a one way ticket, except RDNS which is the only way back.

Comment: @Eun except for maybe providing your own system-wide DNS resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no OS level DNS cache in Android, see

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18002/is-there-a-way-to-list-the-local-dns-cache

Edit: it apparently depends on the Android version. Current releases use Bionic DNS caching, see

http://osxr.org/android/source/bionic/libc/netbsd/resolv/res_cache.c

You can access the cache with [__get_res_cache](http://osxr.org/android/source/bionic/libc/private/resolv_cache.h#0034). This is an in-memory, per-process cache.

If you have access to the configured recursive resolver, you could try to access its cache (e.g. by logging into it, or by installing a service to allow remote access to the cache).

Comment: This sounds like a correct answer, saying `per-process cache` means there is no way to obtain cache for all processes? Also in the implementation it looks like it returns data per interface, not per process.

Comment: Both true: there is no system wide cache, and even the per-process cache then has separate caches per interface (which is sensible, since the recursive resolver configured for an interface might give funny results that don't match the "global" DNS).

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to do what you ask for. There may be ways to grovel through the innards of whatever DNS resolution system you're using to see what has happened to end up in its cache (or similar), but that will be highly system-dependent. No system that I know of has this as a supported function. Some have something that helps (BIND, for example, has `rndc dumpdb` that'll dump the current cache to a file). In any case, you will have to refer to your system's documentation.

Depending on why you want this, the least bad option may be to snoop the relevant network interface for A and AAAA records passing by.

Comment: Can you suggest solution for Android, which is main OS in the question? Because intercepting whole network traffic on all interfaces (and bridges) just to sniff UDP/TCP DNS communication is really overhead.