# HTTPUrlConnection using ip instead of address to avoiding DNS lookup

Tags: java, dns, ip-address, httpurlconnection, host

I want to get a page using it's IP instead host(www.example.com) to avoiding DNS lookup , but how do I achieve that? Right now I am using

```
URL myURL;
            try {
                myURL = new URL(url.getUrl() + "/robots.txt");
                HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
                myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

                System.out.println(response.toString());

                File folder = new File("src/workspace/" + url.getHost());
                folder.mkdirs();
                folder.createNewFile();
                RunCrawler.writeFile("src/workspace/" + url.getHost() + "/robots.txt", response.toString());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want to use for example `172.217.18.164` instead `www.google.com`
Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Comment: The only way i can think of avoiding lookup is if the adress exists in the DNS cache. Accessing the DNS chache is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835421/java-dns-cache-viewer

Comment: @fill͡pant͡ I have my own dns cache implemented from where I get the IP , I just wat to get the page using ip-address

Comment: Oh i see, Sorry for the confusion. Well i belive that by opening the connection on the IP directly does not perform a DNS lookup although i am not certain about that. Anyway if you initialize the field `myURL` with the value `http://172.217.18.164` and you use that to open the http connection it should work fine.

Comment: @fill͡pant͡ Yes it works fine , but I'm not 100% sure if does dns lookup

Comment: Reading the docs i did not find anything to sugest that a lookup (or reverse-lookup) is performed on the paramter adress however i still need to read arround the code to verify this something that appears a litle tricky for the moment...

Comment: @fill͡pant͡ I have tested measuring the time and for ip-address result around 0.02 seconds and with address(www.example.com) was a result of 0.03 seconds .. don't know if means something

Comment: Its hard to judge this based on time as lookup is performed once and is then cached therefore you cant repeat the test  which makes the results unreliable...

What i sugest you do is run a protocol analyser on the machine where the program is ran and check if it picks up any DNS lookups. Using `dns querry sniffer` by nirsoft, i found that when an IP is passed on it is not looked up whereas when a domain is provided which doesnt exist in the cache, a lookup is performed. Still though that may not be generalized to all JVMs and also it is worth testing yourself in case i made some mistake.